# C# Alternatives to Tika

Tags: c#

Anyone Know of any C# alternative to [TiKa](http://tika.apache.org/) able to extract text from HTML,PDF, etc..?

Comment: some questions should not be quickly closed under the allegation of off-topic, from my opinion such actions are very irresponsible and affect the quality services provided by SO website

Comment: agree, totally valid question that would have likely helped someone seeking the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got a similar need... I've got a .Net project where I need to pull text out of various files (.XLS, .DOC, .PDF, etc), for indexing with Lucene.Net

[This blog post](http://blogs.dovetailsoftware.com/blogs/kmiller/archive/2010/07/02/using-the-tika-java-library-in-your-net-application-with-ikvm.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+KevinMiller+(Kevin+Miller)) seems to be exactly what I'm after: A .Net wrapper around the .jar file!

I'm implementing it now, but if it doesn't work then I'll update my answer here...

**Edit:** Ok, it's up, running, and working well (if a little slowly). There's some pretty nasty dependency wrangling with the IKVM bits, but it's the best alternative that I've found.

Comment: Look promising. I will give it a shot. Thanks!

Comment: I am the author of the blog post mentioned. The result of this post is the project TikaOnDotnet. You can find out more at this link. https://kevm.github.io/tikaondotnet/

Answer (score 6):

I've implemented a framework called Toxy. It's based on .NET and easier to use than Tika.
Please visit http://toxy.codeplex.com

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little vague, but for parsing HTML you can use the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) which gives you full DOM access to the HTML and allows extracting elements using XPath expressions.

Comment: Vague no, concise yes. Tika is a Text extracter/parser that will pull out Text which I'll use with Lucene for indexing. I'm seeking something like it for C#.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lucene.Net and try some parsers.... I have just found this blog that has some cool links... I hope it helps!

http://kalanir.blogspot.com.ar/2008/08/indexing-pdf-documents-with-lucene.html